# Oracle sql query issue ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have an sql query inside a java class. when i run it it gives me this error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. I found similar problems but i can't seem to understand what i am doing wrong.

The query is :

```
        String sqlQueryCM = "insert into customers_messages"
            +" (customer_id, message_id, status)"
            +" select gc.customer_id,? as gm.message_id, 0"
            +" from groups_customers gc join cgroups cg on gc.group_id = cg.id"
            +" join groups_messages gm on gc.group_id = ?"
            +" join messages m on gm.message_id = m.id left"
            +" join customers_messages cm on gc.customer_id = cm.customer_id and gm.message_id = cm.message_id"
            +" where cm.message_id = ?"
            +" and m.message_published = 1"
            +" and (cg.start_date is null or to_char(cg.start_date,'YYYYMMDD') <= to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))"
            +" and (cg.end_date is null or to_char(cg.end_date,'YYYYMMDD') >= to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))"
            +" and (m.start_date is null or to_char(m.start_date,'YYYYMMDD') <= to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))"
            +" and (m.end_date is null or to_char(m.end_date,'YYYYMMDD') >= to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))"
            +" and cm.status is null";
```

Comment: i tried but it is the same problem..

Comment: @dic19: value is not needed in that case. see [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html)

Comment: try to define `0 as SomeField`

Comment: Can you enable SQL logging and see what is actually sent to the DB?

Comment: i think it is somehow bad formatted but i can't seem to figure out what

Comment: You don't need a values keyword with this type of query.  You also don't need aliases.  Maybe that's messing you up.  I also suggest that you run just the select part with  hard coded values until you get it working.  Then add the parameters.  Then make it an insert query.

Comment: I'm not sure you can qualify a column as you've done with "? as gm.message_id". When I take your query into [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4992b) and change this to a hardcoded value, then the "FROM  keyword" error goes away, so I suspect this is your problem.

Comment: yes..i think that was the problem, with that identyfier, thank you @wwkudu

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line

```
+" join customers_messages cm on gc.customer_id = cm.customer_id and gm.message_id = cm.message_id"
```

by

```
+" join customers_messages cm on (gc.customer_id = cm.customer_id and gm.message_id = cm.message_id)"
```

edit: replaced the final ( by a ). Sorry for the typo.